# How to maintain transaction integrity per common column value for inserting into two tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have two table variables declared as below:

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (
  A INT,
  B NVARCHAR(100)
)

DECLARE @Table2 TABLE (
  A INT,
  C NVARCHAR(100)
)
```

Here are the contents of @Table1:

```
1, 'Hello'
2, 'Hi'
3, 'Ola'
```

These are the contents of @Table2:

```
1, 'my old friend'
1, 'sweetheart'
2, 'buddy'
4, 'the end'
```

Now I want to insert @Table1 into a table X and @Table2 into a table Y. The scenario is that I have to maintain transaction integrity for the insertion into both X and Y for every same value of column A.

For instance, let's say I am inserting the first row (1,'Hello') of @Table1 into X. This means I must also insert the first two rows ((1,'my old friend'), (1,'sweetheart')) of @Table2 into Y in the same transaction. So if any insert of Y fails for A=1, X also fails for A=1. For any value of column A that is not in both @Table1 and @Table2, they are individual transactions by themselves (e.g. A=3 in @Table1 and A=4 in @Table2).

Here are the ways I see to deal with this problem:

1. I fetch all values of A in both @Table1 and @Table2, run a cursor over it and then for each value of A, I insert into tables X and Y in a single transaction. The issue here is first of all, I don't want to use cursors as much as possible and also, this would mean a super large number of individual inserts.
2. I pre-validate my @Table1 and @Table2 values and then do one single insert of @Table1 on X and @Table2 on Y. This will be much faster than the above method. But the issues I see here are that first of all, not putting it in a 'transaction' somehow doesn't seem right and also, there could be a small chance I might have missed a validation somewhere (unlikely, yet still).

Which approach should I go for? Is there a better solution?

P.S. Please also note that I do not want to fail the entire insert on X and Y if there is an issue in inserting for only one or few values of A. Also, going back and deleting tables from my DB based on the failed inserts is also not an option as it messes with the running id continuity which I am trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

A DML statement is executed completely or not executed at all.

You can do a mix of your two options

First add as much validations as possible, if it fails run the second one using a temp table instead of a cursor

```
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRAN Opt2
    --Option 2
    COMMIT TRAN Opt2
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRAN Opt2
    DECLARE @A INT, @B VARCHAR(100)
    SELECT * INTO #TMP FROM @Table1
    WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #TMP)
    BEGIN
        SELECT TOP 1 @A = A, @B = B FROM @Table1
        -- Option 1
        DELETE #Temp WHERE A = @A
    END
END CATCH
```